# Actualización de la hora actual

Tags: java, hilos, javafx

He implementado este código que paso a un label en una escena.
El problema que tengo es que me muestra la hora a la que arranco el programa, pero no me la actualiza.
¿Qué hago mal o qué falta?

```
@FXML private Label timeLabel;

private int minute;
private int hour;
private int second;

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    Thread clock = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (;;) {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                //System.out.println(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);
                timeLabel.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);

                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                     //...
                }
            }
        }
    };
    clock.start();
}
```

Además me lanza la excepción

**Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3**

Pero no detiene la ejecución

Comment: Si no metes ese código en una clase no correrá, sería más útil que hicieras un [mcve], de esa manera si alguien quiere ayudarte y no ha usado JavaFx en digamos unos 6 años solamente tendría que copiar y pegar tu código en vez de tener que recordar como usar la clase Application en vez de enfocarse en como ayudarte, por ello mismo tal vez no recibas respuestas pronto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema que encuentras en este código está relacionado a un problema común que se da cuando se hacen aplicaciones que corren en múltiples hilos, pero requieren Cambiar componentes visuales.

Hay que destacar, que es mala práctica en Swing (e incluso causa problemas visuales) actualizar componentes visuales en un Hilo que no es el *EVT*(*event Dispatch Thread*). en el caso de JavaFx este hilo se le llama "*FX application thread*" y este tiene reglas mas estrictas que en el caso de Swing.

por tanto, en el caso específico de JavaFx. cuando un hilo que no es el hilo "*visual*(el que manipula el UI)" se debe utilizar herramientas para enviar la tarea visual de vuelta a este hilo de ejecución. 
en JavaFx existen varias formas de lograr esto entre ellas:

las herramientas en el paquete `javafx.concurrent`[link al javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html)

para ejemplos de cómo utilizar las herramientas de este paquete recomiendo la lectura de este articulo: [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

otro método el cual en este caso implica menores cambios es el uso de `javafx.application.Platform` en particular el método `runLater(Runnable runnable)`[referencia Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) de esta forma puedes ejecutar tu hilo en paralelo y cuando una actualización a un componente visual es necesario se hace un llamado con `Platform.runLater(()->{<definición de un thread que ejecute algo visual>});`

por tanto, en el ejemplo se debe modificar el Hilo`clock`de la siguiente forma

```
Thread clock = new Thread(()->{
    while (true) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        System.out.println(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);
        Platform.runLater(()->{timeLabel.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);});
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //... 
        }
    }
});
clock.start();
```

por tanto como se puede ver se utiliza `Platform.runLater(()->{timeLabel.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);});` para enviar el evento a la interfaz de usuario.

puntos a destacar:

es posible que el `Platform.runLater()` tarde una cantidad de tiempo en ser ejecutado y esto puede causar retraso (dado a que la información que se desea demostrar en el UI es "tiempo" es posible que esta implementación no sea adecuada puesto el tiempo que se muestra puede estar "deprecado" para cuando el valor sea mostrado en el UI) ~1 segundo de diferencia entre la hora real vs la hora mostrada? **tome esto en consideración** otro detalle es que el `Thread.sleep(1000)` no garantiza que el hilo "duerma" Exactamente 1 segundo, puede ser más o menos. y esto también puede causar una discrepancia en el cómo se ejecute este "reloj" 
pero se parte del supuesto esto es para un ejemplo y no una aplicación a producción (o eso espero)

otra observacion:

```
private int minute;
private int hour;
private int second;
```

estas variables son utilizadas por 2 hilos de ejecusion pero no existe un lock o son `volatile` lo cual lo hacen problematicas y pueden causar problemas al ser utilizadas por multiples hilos. para evitar este problema se debe utilizar `volatile` o variables atomicas. 
referencias:

[variables atomicas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

[variables y palabra clave `volatile`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html)

[mas sobre las diferencias entre las 2 anteriores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-between-atomic-volatile-synchronized)

[lectura recomendada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708931/javafx-working-with-threads-and-gui)